# Show progress of model being trained using tensorflow keras in my GUI progressbar

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training my model in keras using the following code
`history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)`
It surely displays the progress of the model which is being trained in the output window/terminal. But what i want to do is to run a function at each epoch which is done training and basically update my GUI progressbar.
For example:

```
def update_gui(epoch_number):
   ''' This method should be called after each epoch with the epoch number as an argument and then i will use it to update my GUI'''
   mygui.progressbar.setValue(epoch_number)
```

tensorflow version 2.0.0

Comment: Take a look at [callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#on_epoch_end) and the `on_epoch_end` hook. You can write a custom callback which calls your function.